# Trouble using self created gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Kind of new to this.  I am trying to create my own gem, for logging values into a db. I want to call them gem from other scripts.  If I run the the gem itself it works,  but when I try to 
require and run it from another script, it does not seem to see the variables outside of the class.  Again,  first, gem and class attempt,  any help will be appreciated.

This works:

```
#---Get Data to be Logged---#
class Logit
 def getmsg(msg)
   @msg = msg
 end
end

logit = Logit.new
msg = logit.getmsg("'MMM', '01', 'File XYZ.csv failed to download', 'testScript.rb','batch', ''")
puts msg

#---Split data in to fields---#
fields = msg.split(',')
custodian = fields[0].tr_s('\'', '').strip
msg_level = fields[1].tr_s('\'', '').strip
msg_text = fields[2].tr_s('\'', '').strip
subject = fields[3].tr_s('\'', '').strip
username = fields[4].tr_s('\'', '').strip
manager = fields[5].tr_s('\'', '').strip
```

puts custodian

However when I try it from a script, it fails to see vars.  What am I doing wrong.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'logit'
logit = Logit.new
msg = logit.getmsg("'MMM', '01', 'File XYZ.csv failed to download',
```

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler?  I looked on the RubyGems site and it looks like there is already a logit gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/logit

Comment: Yes, I followed the steps.  This is different type of logging as I need to log to a db and not flat file.

Comment: The last line of the second code block seems incomplete.